# PHP, MySQL - My own version of SALT (I call salty) - Login Issue

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Ok I wrote my own version of SALT I call it salty lol don't make fun of me.. Anyway the registration part of my script as follows is working 100% correctly.

```
    //generate SALTY my own version of SALT and I likes me salt.. lol
    function rand_string( $length ) {
        $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz1234567890";
        $size = strlen( $chars );
        for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
            $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
        }
        return $str;
    } 
    $salty = rand_string( 256 );

    //generate my extra salty pw 
    $password = crypt('password');
    $hash = $password . $salty;
    $newpass = $hash;

    //insert the data in the database
    include ('../../scripts/dbconnect.php');

    //Update db record with my salty pw ;)
                                           // TESTED WITH AND WITHOUT SALTY 
                                          //HENCE $password and $newpass
    mysql_query("UPDATE `Register` SET `Password` = '$password' WHERE `emailinput` = '$email'");
    mysql_close($connect);
```

However my LOGIN script is failing. I have it setup to TEST and echo if its login or not. It always returns FAILED. I entered the DB and changed the crypted salty pw to "TEST" and I got a SUCCESS. So my problem is somewhere in this LOGIN script I assume. Now I am not sure how to implement my $Salty in this. But also be advised that even without SALTY (just using crypt to store my pass) - I was still unable to perform a login successfully. And if you're gonna suggest i use blowfish - note that my webhost doesn't have it supported and i don't know how to install it.

here's my login script:

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) 
{
include ('../../scripts/dbconnect.php');

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = crypt(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

$qry = "SELECT ID FROM Register WHERE emailinput='$username' AND Password='$password'"; 
$result = mysql_query($qry);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    echo 'SUCCESS';
    //START SESSION
}
else
{
    echo 'FAILED';
    //YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN     
}
}
```

1. So what's wrong with this login? Why isn't it working just using the crypt/storing only crypt?
2. How can i make it work storing both the crypt and randomly generated SALTY :) ?

Ty advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the following tweaks to your code:

```
function rand_string( $length ) {
    // added period and slash to the alphabet
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz1234567890./";
    $size = strlen( $chars );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
    }
    return $str;
}

// we need 22 random characters
$salty = rand_string(22);
// apply blowfish with cost := 13
$newpass = crypt($password, sprintf('$2y$%02d$%s', 13, $salty));
```

This uses Blowfish to hash your password; it takes roughly 0.5s to complete at strength 13, so depending on your situation you may want to lessen it; the cost can be changed for newer passwords.

The salt is stored together with the password btw, so there's no need to have another column for that.

To verify the password from database you have to first load the password field from the respective `Register` row.

```
if (crypt($_POST['password'], $password_from_db) === $password_from_db) {
    // success
} else {
    // password didn't match
}
```

Btw, the comparison function is often turned into a constant time algorithm to prevent timing attacks.

---

Your `salty()` function can be replaced with the following equivalent to produce 22 char long salts:

```
substr(strtr(base64_encode(openssl_pseudo_random_bytes(18)), '+', '.'), 0, 22);
```

---

See also: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash

Answer (score 2):

Every time this code runs, you will be generating a DIFFERENT salt value. So when the password is first stored, your salt will be (making up some example stuff) `abc`. You crypt your password (say it comes out to be `123`, attach the salt, and end up with `123abc`, which you store in the database.

When you try to log in next time, you generate a new random salt (say, `456`). You crypt the password, append the salt, and now you've got `123456`. And there's your problem. now you've got two completely different strings, so your login fails.

You need to store the salt separately from the crypted text, so you can REUSE the salt again later. That means your login script first has to retrieve the salt associated with whatever user is trying to log in, recrypt/salt the password they entered, and see if the strings match.

And in a bigger picture view, you're also using the salting incorrectly. The salt must be added to the password **BEFORE** you run the password through crypt. Salts are there to increase the difficulty in brute forcing the password. `123` is a simple password, but `123big_long_ugly_salt_value` isn't.

All you're doing is some useless random number generation that only increases your cpu and storage overhead, but does nothing to increase security.

Answer (score 1):

So in the storing you are crypting 'password' then appending $salty (which is a rand_string)

However in the password compare later you are crypting $_POST['password'], and not appending the same random string. So they would not be the same.

Instead of generating the salt randomly with each password storing procedure you will end up storing a salt somewhere, or creating the salt from something that you can be sure to find again later for the comparison when the login happens again.

Some ideas of how to get this working now would be for you could use the user id, or or some other info that will not change as your salt if you want each user to have a different salt. Or if that doesn't matter you could use some other random string of your own to use.

And as Mark B said in his answer, you should append the salt BEFORE you crypt. Appending it after really is not securing the password.

When using the crypt function you can add your salt right in the function call:

crypt($password, $salt);

And I would not really mess with the mysql_real_escape_string for the password, since you are crypting it. There is not really any worries about injection since you are crypting the possible naughty string.

Comment: What is the result if you echo mysql_num_rows($result) ?

Comment: If I try the username with the crypt pw - result = FAILED, the username with the simple pw - result = success

Comment: I edited my answer. I think this is the real issue after a closer look.

Comment: Adam - I want to use salty. However I am not sure how to implement it so I was asking for advice and how to do so. I guess you're saying I need to store the random gen string and then call it in the POST. But even so I am still having issues not using SALTY.. See I bypassed SALTY and only used crypt to store the pw in the DB, yet still it will not work.

Comment: Generally you would need to store the salt somewhere, so you can use it to recreate the password later for comparison. However, do not store it in your form. Usually would be stored in a config or ini file somewhere.

Comment: I see will investigate that further. Any idea how I get this working just using crypt for the time being would be helpful.

Comment: You could use the user id, or or some other info that will not change as your salt if you want each user to have a different salt.  Or if that doesn't matter you could use some other random string of your own to use.

Comment: And as Mark B said in his answer, you should append the salt BEFORE you crypt. Appending it after really is not securing the password.

Comment: Updated my answer to include more tips on crypt.

Comment: Ty Adam - I will keep try your suggestions